# Automatically send mail using Python

Tags: python, email, gmail, python-3.6

How to send Automatic emails using python 3.6.8 using pycharm

I could install smtplib package I am getting the error: could not find a version that Satisfies the requirement smtplib from versions: None
Error: no matching distribution found for smtplib

Comment: have your tried `import smtplib` first ?

Answer (score 0):

smtplib is part of python standard library. List of standard python libraries are listed here https://docs.python.org/3/library/ . It is automatically installed with the python setup (No need to install it separately). Just import the smtplib in your program and start using it.

Comment: import smtplib
content="hii"
mail=smtplib.SMTP("smtp.mail.com",587)
mail.ehlo()
mail.starttls()
mail.login("www.mokshithspergade@gmail.com","passward")
mail.sendmail("www.mokshithspergade@gmail.com","pergademokshits@gmail.com",content)
mail.close()

Comment: I tried with this above-mentioned code I am getting following errors
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/INDIA/PycharmProjects/excel/email.py", line 2, in <module>
    import smtplib
  File "C:\Users\INDIA\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\smtplib.py", line 47, in <module>
    import email.utils
  File "C:\Users\INDIA\PycharmProjects\excel\email.py", line 4, in <module>
    mail=smtplib.SMTP("smtp.mail.com",587)
AttributeError: module 'smtplib' has no attribute 'SMTP'

Comment: Rename your script to something other than email.py.